# Intuitive understanding of the -b in this definition of a plane

Tags: linear-algebra

I am learning about [SVMs](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/support-vector-machines-the-linearly-separable-case-1.html) in computer science. The book I'm reading defines a hyperplane with an "intercept term", b

$\vec{w}^T \vec{x}= -b$

What does this intercept mean, intuitively? From [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra/vectors_and_spaces/dot_cross_products/v/defining-a-plane-in-r3-with-a-point-and-normal-vector), I understand how the dot product of a vector on a plane, $\vec{a} $ and a normal vector to that plane $\vec{n}$, i.e. I see how $\vec{a}\cdot\vec{n}^T=0$ would define a plane. (because the normal dotted with any vector on the plane is zero).

But what is the $-b$, intuitively, in $\vec{w}^T \vec{x}= -b$?

Comment: Hint: A plane that doesn't pass through the origin is written $n\cdot (x-p)=0$, where $p$ is any point on the plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not too complicated. Let us imagine $n=3$. Suppose we are looking for plane whose unit normal is ${\bf{n}}$ and passes through the point ${{{\bf{x}}_0}}$. Now the equation of all point lying on this plane will be

$$\eqalign{
  & {\bf{n}}.\left( {{\bf{x}} - {{\bf{x}}_0}} \right) = 0  \cr 
  & {\bf{n}}.{\bf{x}} - {\bf{n}}.{{\bf{x}}_0} = 0  \cr 
  & \left\{ \matrix{
  {\bf{n}}.{\bf{x}} + b = 0 \hfill \cr 
  b =  - {\bf{n}}.{{\bf{x}}_0} \hfill \cr}  \right. \cr} $$

and hence your $b$ is minus of the dot product of unit normal and position vector of a special point on the plane. I emphasize that it is just a matter of notation and nothing more. See the below picture

[image]

Comment: why do you set b equal to -n dot x_0 ? Can you give a spatial explanation?

Comment: In fact $ - {\bf{n}}.{{\bf{x}}_0}$ is set to ${\bf{b}}$ just for simplifying notations and using some abbreviation. That's all.

Comment: see the added picture. :)

Comment: so you can think of X_0 going to a special point. There could be infinite planes pivoting from the tip of X_0 in that special point (by rotating/twising the plane in any direction). However, the dot product between the normal and X_0 must equal some value, b. I'm almost there I think -- but why *negative* b?

Comment: Take a look at the answer again

Comment: thanks for the help! Is my understanding "so you can think of X_0 going to a special point..." correct?

Comment: Yeah! Of course it is! :) $x_0$ is a special point while $x$ is an arbitrary point on the plane. :) Got it?